# Sensors to use in Pets

Tags: sensors

I want to track my pets using some sensors (their location in space) but I could only find radio sensors. These radio sensors are big and cumbersome for my dogs to carry around.

Is there some sensor that I can use in order to locate them in space? I want to use my arduino board to capture the data.

Comment: Something like https://www.adafruit.com/products/746?

Comment: Is it inside or outside? You could place sensors on the ground around the dog to track where he is. Or are you looking for something like indeed a GPS 'sensor'? Do you want the data to be stored on the arduino/sd or transmitted directly? Add these things to your question, tracking items/pets can be done in a lot of ways.

Comment: @fuaze want to track them inside an apartment. Got count on walls and obstacles.

Comment: @Gerben, YES. that seems to solve it.

Comment: @Gerben, actually I would need something less fancy, but in the same vein. I'm interested only in raw data (distance from a certain point in 2D)

Comment: What kind of range are you talking about? I doubt you'll be able to do it cheaper than with a GPS unit though.

Comment: @Gerben talking about 100m^2

Comment: A cool project would be to use a camera to track the pet. But you'll need to hook it up to the PC to process the data and then send it to arduino, you wouldn't even need a pet, and probably not even an arduino.
But GPS is probably the best, though I'm not sure how accurate they are, inside an appartment.
Maybe even an accelerometer to check his speed/heading is enough? You should be able to guess where he is/goign from the data?
Or put ping sensors around the room, that measure the distance from the wall to said pet.List the possibilities (pros and cons) and choose the best one I guess.

Comment: @FuaZe accelerometer is a great idea. do you have some reference? I would need something easily rechargeable, for the pets to carry around

Comment: You are aware that an accelerometer does not provide a location by itself? And well, I've actually never used an accelerometer, you should check some tutorials I think.